# Semaphore waiters order

Tags: linux, pthreads, semaphore

We want to work with semaphores in linux (and with pthreads).

We need to know first if the waiters on a semaphore are waiting on it a FIFO fashion.. Meaning, the last to wait for the semaphore will get it last.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual page at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/sem_post.html
it's not a FIFO waiting queue:

> [PS] [Option Start]  If the Process Scheduling option is supported,
>   the thread to be unblocked shall be chosen in a manner appropriate to
>   the scheduling policies and parameters in effect for the blocked
>   threads. In the case of the schedulers SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR, the
>   highest priority waiting thread shall be unblocked, and if there is
>   more than one highest priority thread blocked waiting for the
>   semaphore, then the highest priority thread that has been waiting the
>   longest shall be unblocked. If the Process Scheduling option is not
>   defined, the choice of a thread to unblock is unspecified. [Option
>   End]
>
> [SS] [Option Start] If the Process Sporadic Server option is
>   supported, and the scheduling policy is SCHED_SPORADIC, the semantics
>   are as per SCHED_FIFO above. [Option End]